# enable form in windows form c#, enable doesnt changes when i change it

Tags: c#, windows, forms

```
        private void DisableControls(Control control)
        {
            foreach (Control con in control.Controls)
            {
                DisableControls(con);
            }
            control.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void EnableControls(Control control)
        {
            if (control != null)
            {
                control.Enabled = true;
                EnableControls(control.Parent);
            }
        }
```

for some reason the control.enabled doesn't change at all.
I can't understand why :(, I'm open to any suggestion's instead of the EnableControls function. 
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: How are you using it? Your `DisableControls` method recursively disables all the children where as your `EnableControls` method just enables their parents recursively. There is a subtle difference here.

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I didn't try to do this, thank you a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a logic problem, see what you doing:

- Take one control = Ctrl1
- Disable any control who the parent is the Ctrl1
- Disable Ctrl1

So...

- Take one control = Ctrl2
- Enable Ctrl2
- Enable the **parent, and parents of parents** of Ctrl2

You see? You just re-enable the parents, but not the "brother controls". So you just have to receive a parent, set enable for true and set also all the chields to true.